# When exactly are keys useful in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I still don't quite get the use of keys even after reading through the docs but I understand that it has to do with keeping each item unique.  I've been solely adding a key when using a `v-for` and only to the outer most parent (not the children of the `v-for`.  Are there any other situations when `keys` should be used?

```
<div v-for="(person,index) in people" :key="index>
    <div class="name-label>
       <img :src="person.img/>
       <div> {{ person.name }} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the docs go over it pretty well.  See this [section](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).  It's used to help vue's diffing algorithm so they can reuse as much of the DOM as possible when making updates and to make sure it's removing/changing the correct elements.

Comment: @dippas what do you mean

Comment: @HayleeGal58 I think that was @dippas attempt at humor... referring to your typo `<img :src="person.img/>` instead of `<img :src="person.img" />`

Comment: you're not closing attributes here `:key="index>` , `:src="person.img/>` and `class="name-label>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a unique key in vue.js used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978853/whats-a-unique-key-in-vue-js-used-for)

Answer (score 1):

The `key` directive alongside `v-for`, is used to uniquely identify each parent element rendered on the `v-for` operation.

The same happens in Reactjs:

```
{elements.map((value, index) => {
   return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
})}
```

The `key` directive in Vuejs is also used to force Vuejs to re-render an element that contains it every time `:key` receives a new value.

Answer (score 1):

As @firmino-changani indicated, other uses of `key` is if you want Vue to force a re-render or replacement of an element or component. See `key` special attribute [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key):

> It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component
> instead of reusing it. This can be useful when you want to:
>
> - Properly trigger lifecycle hooks of a component
> - Trigger transitions For example:
>
> ```
> <transition>
>  <span :key="text">{{ text }}</span>
> </transition>
> ```
>
> When text changes, the `<span>` will always be replaced instead of patched, so a transition will be triggered.

Another example, lets say you have a dialog popup to add new data and another component that needs updating once the new data was entered via the popup. This second component might have logic inside lifecycle hooks like `onMounted` etc. Using a `:key` you can force re-rending this component once the dialog popup is saved e.g.

```
<template>
 <page>
   <add-data-popup @save="myKey++" />
   <show-data :key"myKey" />
 </page>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the vueJs docs around Keys:
`The key special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue’s virtual DOM algorithm to identify VNodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list.`

To simply put it, if a div is rendered via a For-loop the div will be identical to each other div. When a user clicks on one of these Div's and you instantiate a @click function, how will vueJs know what differentiates each of these divs? How will vue know how to reorder these div's in the correct order if you remove a middle div?

`VueJs uses the key to know how to reorder the DOM when an action is taken on one of these objects in your For loop.`

Here is an article fully explaining about vueJs keys, and more details on the VueJS reactivity engine which is good to know about: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/in-vue-when-do-i-actually-need-the-key-attribute-and-why